# Powering a remote circuit (operating at 5 VDC, 500 mA)

Tags: power, batteries

As per my application described in [my earlier question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/523826/transmitting-vcc-and-gnd-signals-for-use-with-rs-485), can someone please suggest whether I should power a remote circuit (placed inside a water tank on a terrace):

- with a battery (AA/AAA batteries or Li-Battery or any other one, along with optional small solar panel for charging the battery)

or

- using DC power lines that will be supplied from my home (5-10 m away from the remote circuit).

The remote circuit will most probably be working at 5 VDC with max current consumption of 500 mA.

I want to decide the same on the basis of involved complexity and cost of the above solutions that will be worth it for my requirements.
Any other/new suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: The answer posted for your original question clearly states that it is simple to use the cable for both power and signal.

Comment: Maneesh, you're posting a lot of questions, asking slightly different aspects of the same question for the same project. That leads to a lot of repeated effort for us on all these same-but-a-little-different questions. The site is not a project discussion forum for you to try out all sorts of possibilities and is not be used as one. Please write one single question that states all - all - of your existing thinking, reasons and findings. Please don't post more 'what about this idea then?' questions where the answerers are expected to do all of the thinking. It's not a personal tutorial site.

Comment: @TonyM I apologize for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Apology accepted, thank you. Take the tour, see how the site works, think through your questions and consolidate them into fewer, well-written ones. Turn this into a positive and make some progress :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with AA Batteries at 500mA you only can expect 3-6 hours of lifetime...

> "with max current consumption of 500mA"

is a bit vague, but to me it indicates, you need another power source concept or a measurement system which is more energy efficient